# Add column to Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables in **MS Access.** For each row in the first table I need to get value from the second table. I tried to do it in `UiPath` when I looped the first table and execute the SELECT query below.

Working Query in **UiPath**:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM MB51aggregated 
where (Amount_in_LC > 0 
  and Material = '"+MaterialNo+"')  
ORDER BY Posting_Date
```

It works, but it is too slow. So I want to create a query that adds a column to the first table with selected values from the second table.

**In MS Access I got these errors:**

UPDATEABLE QUERY Error: *Operation must use an updateable query.* - but database is not set as Read-only, Col NewLine I added manually

```
UPDATE MB52 
SET MB52.NewLine = (SELECT Posting_Date 
                    FROM MB51aggregated 
                    WHERE (MB51aggregated.Amount_in_LC > 0 
                      and MB51aggregated.Material = MB52.[Material Number]) 
ORDER BY MB51aggregated.Posting_Date);
```

SYNTAX Error:

```
ALTER TABLE MB52 ADD NewCol AS (SELECT Posting_Date FROM MB51aggregated 
WHERE (MB51aggregated.Amount_in_LC > 0 AND MB51aggregated.Material = MB52.[Material Number]) 
ORDER BY MB51aggregated.Posting_Date);
```

TABLE1 MB52

| ID | Storage | Material Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DE25 | 789092 |
| 2 | RO15 | 355678 |
| 3 | DE25 | 355678 |

TABLE2 MB51aggregated

| ID | Storage | Material | Posting_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DE25 | 789092 | 12.01.2020 |
| 2 | DE25 | 789092 | 15.04.2020 |
| 3 | DE25 | 789092 | 18.02.2020 |
| 4 | RO15 | 789092 | 16.05.2020 |
| 5 | RO15 | 355678 | 12.12.2020 |
| 6 | DE25 | 355678 | 11.12.2020 |
| 7 | DE25 | 355678 | 13.12.2020 |

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` is to modify the table schema, not for handling data. Study a primer on SQL and update/insert as well as methods to join tables in select queries.

Comment: Don't bother with ALTER TABLE. Just manually add field to table then run UPDATE action. If the UPDATE statement is not updatable, then might have to use DLookup() or VBA to update the new field. Edit question to show sample data as text tables.